# Schema-aware XML editing in Vim

Tags: xml, vim, xsd

When editing an XML file in IntelliJ IDEA, if the document references a schema, IDEA will fetch the schema and use the information for auto-complete.  It knows which tags are valid in which contexts, so when you hit CTRL-space, it suggests only those tags.  It also highlights any tags that are invalid according to the schema.

Does anybody know of an extension for Vim that provides similar functionality?

Comment: interesting, I'm tempted to have a go at it. Does it work in IDEA only for editing, or also for writing from scratch?  That is, does it require that the entire document be valid; or that the part up to where you are editing be valid; or will it work with a bare fragment? This affects implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing that I've seen for Vim is the [XML Completion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1442) script.

It contains XML definition files for DocBook 4.[234], XSL FO 1.0, XSLT 1.0, Relax NG 1.0, XML Schemas 1.0, SVG 1.1, XHTML 1.1, XInclude 1.0 and OpenOffice 1.0 XML format.

Answer (score 15):

VIM 7+ supports that **by default without any plugins**, it can load XML definition, there are converters for DTD and SchemaNG:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-xml-omni

For example my Vim 7.3 already have definitions for XHTML:

```
$ rpm -ql vim vim-common | grep xml
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html32.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml11.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xsd.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xsl.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xmlcomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/xmllint.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/xmlwf.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/xml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/xml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/docbkxml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/xml.vim
```

Try it, it's worth it. Everything is documented clearly under the link above, I will not copy-paste it here.

Comment: Hm, what else can vim complete?

Comment: The out-of-box xml completion for Vim 7+ is nice, but I've never been able to get the vim2dtd script to actually work to make new definitions for other types of XML. The script hasn't been updated in nearly a decade. I'd kill to have the autocomplete files for dita xml.

Comment: Note this enables completion, but not schema validation. I.e. you're not going to get an error if you create a file that does not conform to your XML schema.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: http://ricardianambivalence.com/2013/02/17/xml-validation-in-vim/

With the `bar.xml` open, you can easily validate against `foo.xsd`. First, save your changes and then hit `:` and enter the following (it's the pipe to the terminal command).

```
:! xmllint --noout --schema foo.xsd bar.xml
```

Comment: This will not be useful if you want live reporting as you type.