# Emacs SSIS "mode"?

Tags: emacs, ssis

I don't like SSIS graphics interface.
Is it possible to program Emacs so that I can create SSIS packages from Emacs?
If yes, where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS fileformat is just xml files so you could in theory edit the files directly and use one of the emacs XML modes. That said the files are pretty complex and I think it would be much more trouble than it's worth.

Shame as I'd also like to be able to create SSIS packages in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the SSIS format, but someone else said it was XML.

You can edit XML within emacs using an XML mode.  SGML mode is builtin and works fine.  There are other XML modes.

If you want schema-specific editing, you can do that too, except it requires you to jump through some hoops.  See

[Schema-sensitive editing in emacs, based on W3C XML Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917337/schema-sensitive-editing-in-emacs-based-on-w3c-xml-schema-not-rng)